# Exception on update() after calling init() for the second time on the same tracker instance

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-tracking, trackerkcf

Consider the following code:

```
import cv2

window_name = "Object Tracking"
source = cv2.VideoCapture(".tmp/2024-01-24 22-53-46.mp4")

tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
selectedROI = None

while True:
    ret, frame = source.read()

    if not ret:
        print("Error: Could not read frame.")
        break

    success = False
    if selectedROI is not None:
        success, object_bbox = tracker.update(frame)

    if selectedROI is not None and success:
        x, y, w, h = [int(coord) for coord in object_bbox]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame, f"Tracking ({x}, {y}) {w}x{h}",
                    (x, y - 10),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 255, 0),
                    2, cv2.LINE_AA)

    cv2.imshow(window_name, frame)

    keyCode = cv2.waitKey(15) & 0xFF

    # Break the loop if 'ESC' or 'q' key is pressed
    if keyCode in [27, ord('q')]:
        break
    elif keyCode == ord('s'):
        selectedROI = cv2.selectROI("Object Tracking", frame, fromCenter=False, showCrosshair=True)
        tracker.init(frame, selectedROI)
    elif cv2.getWindowProperty(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) < 1:
        break

source.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It's working fine until I press `s` key again and select another ROI. After selecting another region on the very next `tracker.update(frame)` call I receive either this exception:

```
    success, object_bbox = tracker.update(frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:650: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arra
ys have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::arithm_op'
```

or another:

```
    success, object_bbox = tracker.update(frame)
cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
```

Worth noting that it's not the case when I use `TrackerCSRT`. With it, I can re-select region as many times as I want w/o issues. The thing is the `TrackerKCF` works way better and faster for my particular use case.

Any ideas on how to re-init TrackerKCF w/o re-instantiating the object? It takes 1.5 sec to create a new instance which is obviously not acceptable for the real-time scenario :)

Comment: It's gonna be difficult to diagnose the problem without the input video. Can you inspect the `shape` of `frame` before/after the call to `init` and during `update`? Also check out the coordinates inside `selectedROI` and make sure they are valid points within the image dimensions.

Comment: @stateMachine you can check the code with any video. Everything is double-checked, and all is fine :)